# MySQL: Optimization GROUP BY multiple keys

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, query-optimization

I have a table PAYMENTS in MySql database:

```
CREATE TABLE `PAYMENTS` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `USER_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `CATEGORY_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `AMOUNT` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `PAYMENT_INDEX1` (`USER_ID`),
    INDEX `PAYMENT_INDEX2` (`CATEGORY_ID`),
    INDEX `PAYMENT_INDEX3` (`CATEGORY_ID`, `USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to get summary amount for each user in ech category. Here is script:

```
select sum(AMOUNT), USER_ID, CATEGORY_ID
from PAYMENTS
group by USER_ID, CATEGORY_ID;
```

MySql's EXPLAIN command shows Extra: "Using temporary; Using filesort"

How to rid of Using temporary & filesort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an index on `(CATEGORY_ID, USER_ID)` but you're grouping by `USER_ID, CATEGORY_ID`.

***Order matters!*** Create an index that covers the `GROUP BY` clause you're actually using — with the fields in the same order.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed order of fields in index and it works without Extras now!

Comment: @VoteyDisciple - Assuming, there is no "PAYMENT_INDEX3", can we use individual indexes in the group by clause?